Matching tables columns to get data from table
If I had the following tables - Field Definition - defines the field captions
FIELD_DEF:



FIELDID
FIELD CAPTION




F1
CAPTION 1


F2
CAPTION 2



Data table: holds the actual data for each field:
DATA_TABLE:



DATAID
F1
F2




1
A
B



This is what the output needs to look like.



DATAID
CAPTIONTITLE
DATA




1
CAPTION 1
A


1
CAPTION 2
B



The data column names correspond to the field captions in the FIELD_DEF. I need the field caption and corresponding data in the same row.
I don't know how to achieve this. If possible, I would like to use a single SQL query.

Unpivot the Data_Table and then it is a small matter of a JOIN to the Field_Def

Relational databases have columns (not fields) and rows ...

Assuming you have many columns.
Here is an option that will dynamically UNPIVOT your data without actually using Dynamic SQL.
Example
Select A.DataID
      ,CAPTIONTITLE  = C.[FIELD CAPTION]
      ,Data          = B.Value
 from  Data_Table A
  Cross Apply ( Select * 
                From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                Where [Key] Not in ('DataID','Other','Colums2Exclude')
             ) B
 Join Field_Def C on B.[key]=C.FIELDID collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Results
DataID  CAPTIONTITLE    Data
1       CAPTION 1       A
1       CAPTION 2       B


the only thing i would changes is ,Data          = B.[key] to ,Data          = B.[value]
but its what I need
